# Problem in creating new window in cocoa Mac on Button click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have two classes, firstView & secondView. 
In firstView.h

```
#import "SecondView.h"
#import "FirstView"


@interface FirstView : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSButton *test;
    secondView *mySecond;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *test;


-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

In firstView.m

```
#import "FirstView.h"


@implementation FirstView
@synthesize test;


-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"HELLO!!!");
    if (!mySecond) {
        // If the second view controller doesn't exist yet, make it!
        mySecond = [[secondView alloc] init];
    }
    [mySecond displayWindow]; 
}

@end
```

In secondView.h

```
#import 


@interface SecondView : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSWindow *progressWindow;
    IBOutlet NSButton *testNew;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet  NSButton *testNew;

- (void)displayWindow;

-(IBAction) buttonClickedNew:(id)sender;

@end
```

In secondView.m

```
#import "SecondView.h"


@implementation SecondView
@synthesize testNew;

- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"HAI!!");

        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Next" owner:self];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)displayWindow {

    if (![progressWindow isVisible]) {
        NSLog(@"ON SECOND!!!");
        [progressWindow setIsVisible:YES];
        [progressWindow orderFront:nil];        
    }

}

-(IBAction) buttonClickedNew:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"GOOD!!!");
}

@end
```

But I am getting the output as....

```
Running…
2011-04-05 16:12:30.400 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HELLO!!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.402 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.404 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.406 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.408 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.409 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.410 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.411 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.413 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.414 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
2011-04-05 16:12:30.415 toDoListMac[6558:a0f] HAI!!
```

secondView 'init' is calling infinite times!
Please..please...help me.....

What I am trying to do is... I want to open another xib/window on a particular action, say button click.... please help me...

Answer (score 0):

There's a class for controlling windows in Cocoa: [NSWindowController](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Why aren't you using it? Subclassing NSWindowController gets you all the nuts and bolts and then you just need to add in the methods specific to your use case. Much much simpler.

Also, it's not clear if these are separate windows or just separate views. If the latter, you'd want to investigate [NSViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html)